# Parse Server crashes on Heroku error code H10

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-platform, npm, parse-server

I built a Parse Server using the following instructions:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-a-parse-server-to-heroku

I forked the repo and connected to Heroku in the "Connect to Github" section. After deploying, it crashed immediately. I'd love to hear ideas on where to look for the issue. From the logs, it seems that the app is trying to look for a module in `../src/cli/parse-server` while the correct path is `../lib/cli/`. How do I find the offending function? Does this error make sense?

My knowledge of Node is pretty much equal to my knowledge of the codebase, which is none. Any help in hunting would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the error logs:

```
2016-04-22T01:31:53.925057+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=63645159-2ce4-44ba-aa3f-344790b58a46 fwd="73.71.103.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2016-04-22T01:31:55.206156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=4a0ed7ae-c0a3-48bf-ad25-bdce23f6edf2 fwd="73.71.103.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2016-04-22T01:32:17.138695+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=6d86e071-6315-44c3-8046-f6f35b7ab28e fwd="73.71.103.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2016-04-22T01:33:14.268016+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=81f44885-3e42-40e5-8231-d0895e8359fa fwd="73.71.103.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2016-04-22T01:33:55.180903+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=e067c524-f43f-4a94-a515-71aa6b46af15 fwd="73.71.103.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2016-04-22T01:40:34.827054+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=aaa44123-7f18-46a5-870c-0f66c323544e fwd="73.71.103.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2016-04-22T01:40:35.848889+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=6a3bc5a2-919d-411a-a680-38586186abc9 fwd="73.71.103.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Here is the output from `heroku logs --tail`:

```
2016-04-22T05:10:01.865874+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-04-22T05:10:04.520885+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-04-22T05:10:07.665001+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-22T05:10:07.665017+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/parse-server
2016-04-22T05:10:07.665016+00:00 app[web.1]: > parse-server@2.2.7 start /app
2016-04-22T05:10:07.665018+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761298+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761299+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761288+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:341
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761301+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761299+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761300+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../lib/cli/parse-server'
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761304+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761305+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761302+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761302+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761307+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761303+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761304+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bin/parse-server:3:1)
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761305+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-04-22T05:10:07.761306+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-04-22T05:10:07.767870+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-22T05:10:07.776118+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-79-generic
2016-04-22T05:10:07.776611+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-04-22T05:10:07.777886+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-04-22T05:10:07.777665+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
2016-04-22T05:10:07.776847+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.10.1
2016-04-22T05:10:07.778065+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! parse-server@2.2.7 start: `node ./bin/parse-server`
2016-04-22T05:10:07.778224+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-04-22T05:10:07.778417+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-04-22T05:10:07.778901+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the parse-server package,
2016-04-22T05:10:07.778575+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server@2.2.7 start script 'node ./bin/parse-server'.
2016-04-22T05:10:07.778744+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-04-22T05:10:07.779055+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-04-22T05:10:07.779218+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-04-22T05:10:07.779372+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/parse-server
2016-04-22T05:10:07.779684+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs parse-server
2016-04-22T05:10:07.779523+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-04-22T05:10:07.780006+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-server
2016-04-22T05:10:07.779841+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-04-22T05:10:07.780154+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-04-22T05:10:07.783577+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-04-22T05:10:07.783814+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-04-22T05:10:07.783995+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-04-22T05:10:08.681220+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-04-22T05:10:08.712121+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-04-22T05:10:10.100723+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gemparseservertest.herokuapp.com request_id=9df1b250-00d7-4324-8b1e-917da40d7e65 fwd="73.71.103.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deployed `parse-server-example` and that fixed it.

Link to the github issue: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1589